# How to send a photo to the drawable folder after take the photo on Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'd create a xamarin android project on visual studio who take a photo from the camera, but I have a problem, I can take the photo but I don't know how I can make to the project after take the photo send the photo to the drawable folder of the project, how can I make this?

The XAML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#c1cdcd"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:id="@+id/imgvw1" />
<Button
    android:text="Take a Photo"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The MainAcivity

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Graphics;
using System;

namespace Droid_Camera
{
[Activity(Label = "Droid_Camera", MainLauncher = true, Icon = 
"@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ImageView imgView1;
    Button btnCamera;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
        imgView1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgvw1);

        btnCamera.Click += BtnCamera_Click;

    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, 
    [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
        imgView1.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "Drawable" folder is a part of the APK and *read-only*, what are you actually trying to do with the image?

Comment: Can I send the photo to some folder? I need store the photo in some folder of the project

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteFileInternal

Comment: you can't modify the resources of the app, you can't send anything to drawable folder.

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");` will give you only really small preview of the image taken, not the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this unfortunately, the `Drawables` folder is a compile time resource that you cannot add to in run time. Otherwise, the `R.java` file would not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments and answers mentioned you cannot add a file at runtime to your `Drawable`. As a matter of fact you cannot add any file to the bundle itself in runtime.

What you can do is add your file to the filesystem. If you want the file to be 'visible' only to your app use `getFilesDir()`. This returns a folder path present in your application sandbox. If it's meant to be a sort of temporary file and is less than 1MB use `getCacheDir()`

If the file is meant to be publicly visible use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` but for this you would need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) for details